# How can I solve CommandNotFoundError in powershell of visual studio code?

Tags: powershell, path, visual-studio-code

when I open terminal of visual studio code.I have a CommandNotFoundError.How can I solve this?
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

```
$ echo ". E:\Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

or, for all users, enable conda with

```
$ sudo ln -s E:\Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

```
$ conda activate
```

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

```
$ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

```
export PATH="E:\Anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^

Comment: To me it sound as if some (anaconda) scripts are interpreting your environment wong. As powershell (core) and VS Code run under Windows,Linux and Mac OS X you should state what your environment ***IS***. Aside from additions (WSL,mingw,Cygwin etc.) Windows won't understand bash scripts.